# Manage project with tasks that can be completed in any order

Tags: ms-project

Probably best described by example:

I have a project with 10 tasks of 1 day to be done by 1 resource. So they have to happen sequentially, easy to arrange by levelling or linking and the project will last 10 days. But this sets a task order, and it seems that Project expects them to be done in that order.

If they are, it is easy to get an indication from the standard reports about overall project progress. I can get a "late tasks" report which will show exactly that.

But the reality in our projects is that each task is done a bit at a time. So after 5 days, we are just as likely to have done 50% of all the tasks, or 100% of the last 5, as 100% of the first five and for us, that is equally satisfactory progress.

I have tried but I can't seem to find a way of knowing if the overall project is on track by work done regardless of task order. Is there an easy answer for this?

Comment: As this question is not about programming, but rather how to use Microsoft Project, it belongs on the [Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/) or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) site.

Comment: thanks I'll try that